# i connected the two vertex but now i can't seem to select the other face on the top half?

Tags: modeling

[image: why? it selected whole of the face instead. I just want that top half section. This is after I connected the two vertex]

why? it selected whole of the face instead. I just want that top half section. This is after I connected the two vertex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have connected the 2 vertices with <kbd>F</kbd> (fill), which won't separate the face in 2 separate faces, but just create an edge between the 2 vertices over the existing face. If you want to connect the 2 vertices in order to cut face in 2 parts, choose <kbd>J</kbd> (join).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Knife Tool (K) if you want to actually cut a face from a vertex to the other. It seems like you just made an edge between those two opposite vertices *on top* of the existing face. Hope this helps.